# Change in cpp file don;t appear in cygwin run

Tags: c++, cygwin

I have windows7 operating system and cygwin for linux simulator. i install one program called "Shawn" for network simulator in cygwin (with hard effort). now when i change .cpp file in windows and run ./shawn in cygwin, the output does not change. can anyone help me?

Comment: you _do_ rebuild the application after changing the source?

Comment: you have to rebuild the project/executable/whatever in cygwin in order to see any change.

Comment: How did you build it the first time?

Comment: with eclipse and create new make target.

Comment: Why not build it again in Eclipse, or run the makefile manually?

Comment: @juanchopanza: you have to rebuild the project/executable/whatever in cygwin in order to see any change.

i build it by click on the old make target node in the make target tab in eclipse.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When changing the source files of a program written in a compiled language (like C++) this does not affect the related binary/executable/program/library until it is rebuilt from the updated sources. This is not specific to cygwin, as it happens in native Windows, Linux or any other OS.

So to make the changes in the source code you did appear in the binary, all you have to do is rebuilding it.